# Format date range for next year

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm trying to get a date range that takes the calendar year after the transaction date. Say if the date was this year then it should be 1/01/2018 - 12/31/2018.

I'm using this syntax but am getting the error that everything after the first line is not part of the formula. Any ideas?

```
Local DateVar d := CDate cstr(year({TransDate}));
Local DateVar Range dr := DateSerial (Year(d)+ 1, Month(d) - 1, 1) To  
                          DateSerial (Year(d)+ 1, Month(d) - 1, 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing parentheses for `CDate` in your first line. Proper syntax would be:

```
Local DateVar d := CDate(cstr(year({?Start Date})));
```

However that still won't work, because the result of a formula cannot be a date range. Instead, separate the range into a `StartDate` and `EndDate` field, then use those for your calculations.

---

*StartDate:* `DateSerial(Year({?Date}) + 1, 1, 1)`

*EndDate:* `DateSerial(Year({?Date}) + 1, 12, 31)`

Comment: So use two formula fields?

Comment: @user1327418 Pretty much. I do a lot of reports with date ranges, and I always use `{Date} >= {StartDate} AND {Date} <= {EndDate}`

Comment: But if you have a given date how do you derive the next year's first of the year?

Comment: @user1327481 Oh that's easy, you're practically already there - I'll update the answer to include the formulas.

Comment: @user1327418 Any luck with the new formulas?

Comment: @user1327418 Great, glad to hear it! Don't forget to mark the answer as Accepted when you're done. Thanks!